# Select and combine all elements as sub list that belongs to the same ID from a JSON response

Tags: c#, json, linq

**Problem**

Below I have a JSON response, in which there are 3 records. There can be multiple records belonging to the same ID, for instance, ID **75029560**. I would like to fetch some data belonging to that ID as a sublist and then move to another ID if there is, please see the **Desired Output** below.

Any help would be great, I am a newbie to C# and LINQ.

**JSON response**

```
{
    'list': [
        {
            'installation': {
                'id': 75029560,
                'identification': 'Bob',
                'name': 'Bob'
            },
            'timeStart': {
                'value': '2019-09-25T08:45:00'
            },
            'wattHourCumulative': 0,
            'wattHourPer15Min': 120,
            'year': 2019
        },
        {
            'installation': {
                'id': 78206452,
                'identification': 'Steve',
                'name': 'Steve'
            },
            'timeStart': {
                'value': '2019-09-25T09:00:00'
            },
            'wattHourCumulative': 0,
            'wattHourPer15Min': 400,
            'year': 2019
        },
        {
            'installation': {
                'id': 75029560,
                'identification': 'Bob',
                'name': 'Bob'
            },
            'timeStart': {
                'value': '2019-09-25T09:00:00'
            },
            'wattHourCumulative': 0,
            'wattHourPer15Min': 170,
            'year': 2019
        }
    ],
    'success': true,
    'totalNumberOfItems': 3
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
    'list': [
        {
            'user': {
                'id': 75029560,
                'data': [{
                     'record': {
                          'wattHourCumulative':  0,
                          'wattHourPer15Min': 120
                      },
                     'record': {
                          'wattHourCumulative':  0,
                          'wattHourPer15Min': 170
                      }]
                 },
            },{
                'id': 78206452,
                'data': {
                     'record': {
                          'wattHourCumulative':  0,
                          'wattHourPer15Min': 400
                      }
                 }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ok so what you want to do is a [group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8). Let us know if that's not the case

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you need a list of objects with variable name of properties in desired output? _to fetch some data belonging to that ID as a sublist and then move to another ID if there is_ Your data is just grouped, not moved

Comment: Desired output is not a valid formatted json. what are you looking for? "user" element in desried cannot be comma separated value, it has to be an array, same thing with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` - parse the response into `JObject`, group by `id` and format the result

```cs
var document = JObject.Parse(json);
var result = document["list"].GroupBy(item => item["installation"]?["id"],
    (id, items) => new
    {
        user = new
        {
            id,
            data = items.Select(i => new
            {
                wattHourCumulative = i["wattHourCumulative"]?.Value<int>(),
                wattHourPer15Min = i["wattHourPer15Min"]?.Value<int>()
            }).ToList()
        }
    });

var jsonObject = JObject.FromObject(new { list = result });
var resultJson = jsonObject.ToString();
```

Please, keep in mind, that your output is incorrectly formatted, the `data` property should be an array, because you group a multiple records, `list` array should contain multiple `user` items.

The result JSON will be the following

```
{
    "list": [{
            "user": {
                "id": 75029560,
                "data": [{
                        "wattHourCumulative": 0,
                        "wattHourPer15Min": 120
                    }, {
                        "wattHourCumulative": 0,
                        "wattHourPer15Min": 170
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "user": {
                "id": 78206452,
                "data": [{
                        "wattHourCumulative": 0,
                        "wattHourPer15Min": 400
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your input helped me a great deal. Also, it showed me what LINQ is capable of. Can I also ask you about **how can I fetch the name, item["installation"]?["name"]**.

Comment: In the same way with other properties actually, depending on which level are you expect it. Are you expect it together with 'id`?

Comment: Then it makes sense to include it into the group by expression

Comment: Or group by entire `installation` object and get the `id` and `name` from it

Comment: I prefer to perform the `Group by` on `Id` because in future if the installing response differs atleast I am not relying on rest of the values then.